# Do I need a default document on IIS for an MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, iis-8

Why should I create a default document in my IIS configuration when creating a web application for my MVC website when the name is customized for example `Login.cshtml`?

I thought via MVC routing there is no need to define any default document on IIS. Or is it that we are assuming that under each controller there is an `index.cshtml` page?

Answer (score 1):

Views are served by MVC, not by IIS. MVC is what controls which URL is mapped to which action method, and it is the action methods that return views.

As long as there is a route in MVC that can serve the URL "" (the default `http://example.com/` path), then there is no need to map a default document in IIS. Note that the `Default` route from the Visual Studio MVC template handles this case, so as long as you don't change it you are covered.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also, it is *highly unusual* to make the `Login` the default page. If you want the entire site to be only accessible by logging in, register the `AuthorizeAttribute` as a global filter.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

When combined with a proper configuration in startup, this ensures any page that is accessed in the web site will *redirect* the request to the login page and redirect back to the requested page when they login. That way when the user is logged in, the "default" page is not always the login page (which doesn't make much sense when the user is logged in).

Comment: I do have a default routing as follows:                                                    \n                                                                                                                           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                //action default Index changes to LogIn
            );

Comment: The default page which i want to load is named as Login.cshtml which is under my View Home folder. I have a controller Home and the action Index is supposed to load this view.  Do I still need to define the Default Document on IIS?

Comment: No, there is no reason for a default document. And as I said, it is not very practical to make your *default action* the login page. Do you really want the user to go to the login page by default when they are already logged in? If not, then use the `AuthorizeAttribute` as I mentioned.